# Keras: How to save GAN model with optimiser state?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network, federated-learning

I know one use can be using Checkpoint and CheckpointManager tensorflow classes to save and resume training the GAN.

I am looking for a way to save the Generator (G) , Discriminator(D) and their optimisation states such that I can manipulate the model weights (for G and D). One use case for me is average the weights of different Generator in Federated Learning for GAN.

I found no way do to this using Keras or tensorflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: With optimization state you mean you want to safe the model with its trained weights or that you also want to save the optimzer?